# Windows 10 Asus P8H67-I - Always boots to VGA (Not HDMI) even when vga not plugged in

Tags: windows-10, hdmi

I am using integrated graphics on Asus P8H67-I motherboard (which has hdmi, dvi and vga ports.)

In Windows 10 every time I set the display to HDMI, it forgets the settings on reboot and only loads the vga port, even if vga is disconnected. The hdmi display shows the bios boot, a few seconds of the Windows logo, then goes black. This is whether or not anything is plugged in vga.

Also, I tried using TightVNC to trouble shoot... if the vga isn't plugged in, VNC also shows a blank screen.

On the blank screen, I can still shut down the computer with the keyboard, so it is responding even though I can't see it.

The only way the hdmi works, is with to enable the hdmi display after it boots up on the vga display.

Driver is Intel HD Graphics 2000 Display driver 9.17.10.4229.

I previously was running openelec operating system on this and it never did this. This is a clean install with only chrome, kodi and TightVNC installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally determined the issue was the video card was outputting at 59hz. Once I changed it to 60hz, my Visio M60-C3 recognized the card and worked fine.